# Announcements possible?

Tags: feature-request

This is really a feature request. I think that StackExchange is **by far** the best "network" out there because it has the lowest barrier to entry and the best content.

We run a local Python User Group and it just seems like it would be a great idea to be able to announce our meetings in the one place which is known by nearly everyone programmer.

What do you think?

Comment: "lowest barrier to entry"... Ugh. Anyway, I don't want to be bothered with every user group in the world spamming SO with meeting announcements.

Comment: Heh. Tough crowd today. Anyway - this isn't really practicable here. Meetup.com is one good place where this might work

Comment: You guys should try Slack.  No joke.

Comment: start (or join) a chat room and make use of it. you can star posts and announcements etc and anyone who visits the room can see them.

Comment: Sure... "Stack got popular because of it's strict focus and quality level.... Now that, using those two things, it became the biggest site of the genre.... Can we disregard those two things for ME?"  sounds like a recipe for disaster

Comment: Thanks for the comments but they're mainly at cross-purposes. SO already has context and location and events could build on that. Would have to be discreet. So far not impressed by Meetup as a platform because it has so little context.

Answer (score 17):

Doing something like that would turn Stack Overflow (and potentially Stack Exchange) into the one thing that it is *not* - a social media site.

Answer (score 12):

> the best "network" out there because [...]

One of the features that makes SO "best" is that the people who've decided what would be shown on the site *besides* questions and answer, have, by and large, avoided loading the site with stuff I don't care about. If I'm going to be subjected to announcements from every local developer group across the world, my opinion of SO will tank quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I've obviously expressed myself badly. I'm as against flooding people with nonsense as the next but I can see space in the sidebar for something like events related to the current context and location.